# Validity of implementing a Morton Z-curve in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a cellular automata, which involves read/writing to a 2-dimensional array many times a second, specifically neighbouring cells. I understand data locality reduces cache misses and **should** increase performance in my case, massively so I've heard. I decided to implement a [morton z-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), which seemed the fastest to convert its index in the 'z-curve array' to a corresponding x,y coordinate in the 2d array. However, I've profiled many algorithms, and none seem to be capable of accessing each cell in the array and editing its neighbours **anywhere close** to as fast as a standard 2-d array type that c# supports (by at best half speed, and at worst 1/10 of the speed).

I've tried increasingly fast algorithms to convert x/y coordinates to z-indexes, but still the mighty 2d array is just faster. These include the 'magic bit' and lookup table methods as shown: [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableLookup). It makes no sense. Are cache misses and data locality simply not that big of a deal, and are outweighed by the processing required to convert between the z-array and the 2d array? Please bare in mind how simple the conversions actually are, merely interleaving the binary for the x and y coordinate will produce the z index.

Is this a futile effort? Is C# simply not capable in circumstances such as this?

Comment: "... data locality reduces cache misses and should increase performance in my case" - what makes you think this applies significantly in your specific case?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen for each cell, I need to access that cell's neighbours. Wouldn't data locality help in this situation? Compared to row or column major order, neighbouring cells should (on average) exist closer to each other in memory.

Comment: Really hard to tell without knowing the size of your arrays, whether your comparing against jagged or multidimensional arrays, etc. Maybe post the two implementations in the question and describe the parameters with which you get worse performance with the curve?

Comment: Without implementation details any answer to this question would remain vague and opinion-based.